# onAnimationEnd is not getting called for imageview rotation animation

Tags: android

I have two ImageViews, one is rotating clockwise & other anti-clockwise.
Same code is working for other animation but for rotation, `onAnimationEnd`  is not getting called.

onAnimationEnd is not getting called here.

```
public class ObcActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Animation.AnimationListener {

    ImageView circularImageView1;
    ImageView circularImageView2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(  R.layout.activity_obc);
//        setContentView(  new HeartbeatView(this));

        clockAnimation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_clockwise);
        antiClockAnimation =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_anticlockwise);
        clockAnimation.setAnimationListener(this);
        antiClockAnimation.setAnimationListener(this);
        clockAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
        antiClockAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
        clockAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
        antiClockAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
        circularImageView1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circularImageView1);
        circularImageView2= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.circularImageView2);
        circularImageView1.setAnimation(clockAnimation);
        circularImageView1.startAnimation(clockAnimation);
        circularImageView2.setAnimation(antiClockAnimation);

    }


    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        Toast.makeText(this,""+System.currentTimeMillis(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(animation==clockAnimation){
            circularImageView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            circularImageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            circularImageView1.clearAnimation();
            circularImageView2.startAnimation(clockAnimation);
        }else {
            circularImageView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            circularImageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            circularImageView1.startAnimation(antiClockAnimation);
            circularImageView2.clearAnimation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }

    Animation clockAnimation, antiClockAnimation;

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#71bf44"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circularImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_circle"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circularImageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/outer_ring_2_white"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circularImageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/outer_ring_3_white"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circularImageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/outer_ring_2_white_out"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circularImageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/outer_ring_3_white_out"
        />




    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]
**Update:**

As per the answers, I set following code which is not working, not calling onAnimationEnd. I need to get event of when animation of first image ends!

```
clockAnimation.setRepeatCount(100);
        antiClockAnimation.setRepeatCount(100);
        clockAnimation.setRepeatMode(100);
        antiClockAnimation.setRepeatMode(100);
```

Comment: can you post your anim files here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have set **INFINITE** in `Animation`

```
clockAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
```

it will start with **infinite** mode means never End

Your animation iteration updatation will notify in `onAnimationRepeat`

```
@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
```

What [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationEnd(android.view.animation.Animation)) saying of method **onAnimationEnd**

> Notifies the end of the animation. This callback is not invoked for
>   animations with repeat count set to INFINITE.

as per **comment**:

> But I need animation end event. for example after 2 rotations.

for that add this lines in code

```
clockAnimation.setRepeatCount(2); 
clockAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
```

Comment: Should I move my code to onAnimationRepeat? But I need animation end event. for example after 2 rotations..

Comment: use `clockAnimation.setRepeatCount(2);` and `clockAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);`

Comment: Yes it worked. You get animationend event with this.. please update the answer..Add these lines too..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) for `INFINITE` animations:

> void onAnimationEnd (Animation animation)
>
> Notifies the end of the animation. This callback is not invoked for
>   animations with repeat count set to INFINITE.

In any event I suggest holding two `Animation.AnimationListener` objects and implementing one in your activity. This would make your code clearer and remove the need to ask questions like `if(animation==clockAnimation)`.